# Tensorboard : No dashboards active for current dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I am training a neural network for object detection using Google Colab.  I wanted to visualize the learning process but every time I try to access tensorboard, it shows me the following:

***No dashboards are active for the current data set. Probable causes: - You haven’t written any data to your event files. - TensorBoard can’t find your event files.***

I am not training the model locally and have configured my google drive account with the colab notebook for the training data so user hpabst's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113472/tensorboard-error-no-dashboards-are-active-for-current-data-set) does not seem useful.

I also tried setting up tensorboard using [ngrok](https://www.dlology.com/blog/quick-guide-to-run-tensorboard-in-google-colab/) but that gave me a similar output.

I made sure I am generating summary data in a log directory by creating a summary writer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/content/logs/my_log_dir/', sess.graph)
```

and followed that with

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="/content/logs/my_log_dir/",batch_size=32, write_graph=True, update_freq='epoch')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=(train_data/BS),
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=(test_data/BS),
        callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
```

and finally

```
tensorboard --logdir /content/logs/my_log_dir/
```

The event files are in place. The path to the log directory is also correct.

Comment: Seems you are missing a `/` in the beginning of the path when calling Tensorboard

Comment: Oh that's a typo. Made the edit.

Comment: are you able to get the tensorboard running in the working example you provided in the ngrok link? See what files are created in the log folder, and compare the files against the log folder your model created.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. As far as I understand, there should be just one set of event files created by the model in my colab virtual machine in the 'my_log_dir' folder. Tensorboard uses the same event files for visualization. There's no second set of event files being generated anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, I was getting the same- ***No active dashboards*** error using ngrok. I moved over to the SCALARS menu in the Tensorboard GUI and to the left, under the runs section, at the bottom, I found out that the path to the log directory was being shown as '/content/ **log** /my_log_dir' although everywhere in my code I had only mentioned the path as -'/content/ **logs**  /my_log_dir'. Maybe setting up tensorboard using ngrok expects the files to be in the 'log' and not the 'logs' directory. I made the change and now it works just fine.